# What is the difference between extensions and php.ini directives?

Tags: php

What is the difference between extensions and php.ini directives?

For example in php.ini directives I saw [`mbstring.http_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) as option, and I also saw it in extensions as [multibyte string extension](http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.php).

Comment: Roughly speaking, the same difference that exists between programs and settings.

Comment: @mina, did you manage to check my answer? will appreciate a vote/accept on it. Thanks!

Comment: @Dekel : I am working on the current status to prove the correctness or not , so once i finished , i will vote , again thank you for replying , caring and answering in general .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directives are general configurations options - settings.
Some you can change at runtime (using the [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set) function), some you can only change using the configuration file (php.ini, or .htaccess).

Extensions are binary-compiled libraries which enable specific functions to be used in your PHP code. They are written in C and loaded dynamically using

```
extension=ext.dll/ext.so ; (based on your OS)
```

Some extensions provides/require also configuration options, and those can be handled/changed exactly the same way any other directive works.

For example, the xdebug extension gives us the ability to [control the output of the var_dump function](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_children) using

```
xdebug.var_display_max_children
xdebug.var_display_max_data
(and more)
```

These **directives** control/affect the **extension** that was loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

An extension, as its name implies, extends the features of the language and runtime. It can add new functions and types to the global scope (for example the [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions from the MySQLi extensions) or change existing implementations so they do things faster or differently.

But the functionality provided by an extension hardly ever fits all scenarios. Enter the settings file: here you can configure parameters known to the extension, so the extension can alter its behavior based on your configuration. See for example [the MySQLi Runtime Configuration page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.configuration.php).